# Question garnered six offensive flags but was not deleted?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags, offensive, deleted-posts

I came across [this post](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/why-people-are-retarded-to-the-point-of-believing-in-a-bearded-wizard-living-high#question)<sup>*</sup>, which had managed to gather six offensive flags...

Normally, [this would result in the question being locked and deleted by the Community user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts).

However, while it *was* locked, it was not deleted. I've since deleted it.

I suspect this is an edge case, as I've not seen this elsewhere... But it could be problematic in cases of moderator absence, as a locked post cannot be closed or deleted by normal users.

<sup>*<sub>deleted - only 9 non-moderators can view at this time</sub></sup>

Comment: Given the subject matter, are you sure they haven't just, um, turned up the dial a little bit? *[ducks]*

Comment: very very few people will be able to see this post you're referring to. Like 10 people.

Comment: Nine. And the moderators. Which are us. But I couldn't see how *not* linking improved matters any. @Jeff

Comment: nine? How is it possible? I see  only one 2k user + mods...

Comment: @genesis: click the little "All" button at top-right. Site's been up for more than this month...

Comment: After looking at the URL,  wow.  Just....wow.

Comment: @Shog9 - have you seen repeats of this? With the amount of change the related code has seen, not sure if this is not obsolete.

Comment: Never seen it again *for this reason* - you can probably mark it [status-norepro] at this point, @Oded.